# How can I format this data result in PHP?

Tags: php

I have this data.

```
   data: {
       {
         id: 1,
         message: "text message"
       },
       {
         id: 2,
         message: "text message again"
       },
       {..},
       {..}
    }
```

Now, **I want it to be like this.** Add **"msg"** as ***index/key***.

```
   data: {
       msg: {
              id: 1,
              message: "text message"
       },
       msg: {
              id: 2,
              message: "text message again"
       },
       msg: {..},
       msg: {..}
    }
```

How can I achieve this? Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Any ideas yourself? Have you tried anything?

Comment: tried json_decode() ?

Comment: @RakeshSharma: Neither of those are valid JSON.

Comment: Google for: 'php array key value'. And read some pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't have keys with the same name in a json data. And please note that isn't valid json.

For example this:

```
data: {
   {
     id: 1,
     message: "text message"
   },
   {
       ...
   }
}
```

should be something like this:

```
{
    "data":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "message":"text message"
        },{ 
            "id":2, 
            "message":"text message again"
        }
    ]
}
```

However trying to reproduce your data I came out with a kind of solution like this :

```
$data = [
    "data" => [
        [
            "id" => 1,
            "message" => "text message"
        ],
        [
            "id" => 2,
            "message" => "text message again"
        ]
    ]
];

var_dump(json_encode($data));

foreach ($data['data'] as $key => $value) 
{
    $data['data']["msg".$key] = $value;

    unset($data['data'][$key]);
}

var_dump($data);
var_dump(json_encode($data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like Notepad++ or Edit-plus.
1. Do Ctrl+H (Replace)
2. Set From text as   "{\n\t id: "
3. SET To   text as   "msg {\n\t id:" 
4. Keep the regular expression check-box as checked.
5. And then click on Replace All button.

Answer (score -1):

A slow way to do it would be this (assuming it's an array):

```
$newData = array();
foreach($data as $item){
    $newData[]['msg'] = $item;
}

var_dump($newData);
```

**EDIT** If it's JSON data, convert it to an array first with `json_decode($data, true)`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for you idea. Instead of using $newData[]['msg'] = $item;
I use this. $newData['msg']['id'] = $item->id. It works.

Comment: It's neither an array or JSON data.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
foreach($data->data as $key => &$val)
{
    $stdO = new stdClass();
    $stdO->msg = $val;
    $data->data[$key] = $stdO;
}
```

Comment: Very obvious thing, the json array user mentioned. This says everything $data->data

Comment: No, actually, it doesn't. It actually says nothing. Since OP has a string, not an array. Also, since you're using the `->` operation, it's implied that you don't have an array either, you have an object. Not to mention that's OP's data is not valid JSON. Currently, this answer is about 20% correct, and 80% incorrect.

Comment: The Data user asking about is in object form not an string and this is valid assumption if you read the question. JSON decoded is object so using -> is valid.